# Is there a noun or adjective for someone who makes trite remarks as if they were new and original?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Usually at the end of a speech, as if such remarks were fresh, and special for the occasion, e.g.

> - I've said it before and I'll say it again: hasty climbers have
>   sudden falls
> - I'm against all that, and you know why? Give them an inch and they
>   will take a yard
> - ...and remember my words: there's no smoke without fire

Comment: What about coining "phrase-boor" ? :-))

Comment: One might call such remarks 'suck-filled platitudes'.

Comment: @ErikKowal Would there be a noun or adjective for the person who uses it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a person could be described as a [*platitudinarian*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platitudinarian), which the online Merriam-Webster defines as

> One given to the use of platitudes ;

or the similar term [*platitudinizer*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/platitudinizer), which Dictionary.com defines as

> [One who] utter[s] platitudes.

However, these descriptors are not in particularly common use. If I personally needed to describe such a person, I'd probably go for something more generic like *reciter of platitudes*, *{tedious / pompous} windbag*, or even *sententious bloviator*.

Comment: Great. Exactly the word I was looking for. Unfortunately, and correct me if I'm wrong, it seems to me I shouldn't use it unless I'm talking to someone who is extremely well-versed in the English language. I mean, if I had heard someone using that word yesterday, I wouldn't understand it.

Comment: If we all only use words that we are sure our entire audience will understand, no one will ever learn any new words...

Answer (score 3):

'Panglossian' is the closest I can get to the word you want. 'Panglossian' is an adjective describing the character in Voltaire's play 'Candide'. Dr. Pangloss is Candide's teacher of philosophy. Dr. Pangloss utters banalities whenever a crisis occurs: e.g., 'Everything is for the best, in this, the best of all possible worlds.' The cliches are delivered by a pedant who dispenses his 'wisdom' as if they were newly discovered truths.